# RxJS TestScheduler accumulating frames

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm unit testing rxjs with jest and I have come to a situation where two different tests inside their own `testScheduler.run` seem to share their total count of frames (unless something else is happening).

Here's my test:

```
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { TestScheduler } from "rxjs/testing";
import { timer, race } from "rxjs";

const testScheduler = new TestScheduler((actual, expected) => {
  expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
});

describe("Testing race conditions", () => {
  it("obs1 should complete first", () => {
    testScheduler.run(helpers => {
      const { cold, expectObservable } = helpers;
      const obs1$ = cold("--a");
      const obs2$ = timer(5000).pipe(map(x => x.toString()));
      const output$ = race(obs1$, obs2$);
      const expected = "--a";
      expectObservable(output$).toBe(expected);
    });
  });
  it("obs2 should complete first", () => {
    testScheduler.run(helpers => {
      const { cold, expectObservable } = helpers;
      const obs1$ = cold("5m --a");
      const obs2$ = timer(5000).pipe(map(x => x.toString()));
      const output$ = race(obs1$, obs2$);
      const expected = "5s (0|)";
      expectObservable(output$).toBe(expected);
    });
  });
});
```

And this are the results:

[image: Results original order of tests]

If I remove the first test, the second one passes and if I invert them, the second one passes and the first fails with these results:

[image: Results of inverted order of test]

Notice how in the first case, the 2 frames from the first successful test are added to the 5 seconds that elapse in the second, making 5002 and failing due to those 2 additional frames. In the second case, the 5 seconds are accumalted for a total of 5002 again, in contrast with 2 that are expected.

I finally solved it by making local `testScheduler` declarations inside the `it` function, which seems odd too me because in the [docs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/testing/marble-testing) it's declared outside, like this:

```
import { TestScheduler } from 'rxjs/testing';

const testScheduler = new TestScheduler((actual, expected) => {
  // asserting the two objects are equal
  // e.g. using chai.
  expect(actual).deep.equal(expected);
});

// This test will actually run *synchronously*
it('generate the stream correctly', () => {
  testScheduler.run(helpers => {
    const { cold, expectObservable, expectSubscriptions } = helpers;
    const e1 =  cold('-a--b--c---|');
    const subs =     '^----------!';
    const expected = '-a-----c---|';

    expectObservable(e1.pipe(throttleTime(3, testScheduler))).toBe(expected);
    expectSubscriptions(e1.subscriptions).toBe(subs);
  });
});
```

So I wanted to know, is this behaviour normal or intentional? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You need to create the `TestScheduler` instance on a per-test basis: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/02f458d26d9a885bbf913c98011e77d251837226/spec/operators/audit-spec.ts#L13-L15

Comment: Re-create the testScheduler in a beforeEach so that every test has its own scheduler.